# Problem querying a specific django object correctly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my (basic) fantasy football app I'm building, I have each player/position represented by an individual model object. Like so. Here's one such model/position.

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

I also have a "Team" model which has information on team name, user, and players in the team. The main purpose of this object is because I want to display a list of all users and their teams and their team's total score so that each user can see how everyone else is scoring.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quarter_back = models.ForeignKey(Quarterback, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    running_back = models.ForeignKey(Runningback, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    wide_receiver = models.ForeignKey(Widereceiver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tight_end = models.ForeignKey(Tightend, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    kicker = models.ForeignKey(Kicker, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

The problem I'm having though is assigning a total score. What I'm trying to do is compare the players'names in Team to a list of players and scores that I've pulled from an api. Let's call it "player_data." If the player in the Team object is in the player_data object, I can then assign the player's score to a variable called "totalscore", tally it, render it to my template, etc. But, I'm having trouble with querying an individual Team object.

My first thought was to make a function in views.py and pass the Team object's id. Something like this.

```
def teamscores(request, id):

    team = Team.objects.get(id=id)
```

With a URL like this.

```
path('teamscores/<int:id>', views.teamscores, name="teamscores")
```

However, I get a 404 error because I can't seem to get the object's id correctly. I think my problem is with the query I'm using, but I really don't know. I'd really appreciate an outside opinion on it.

Answer (score 0):

try using pk instead of id in your query and url

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_object_or_404` like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Team

def teamscores(request, team_id):
  team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=team_id)
```

or if you don't want that you should use `pk`:

```
team = Team.objects.get(pk=team_id)
```

You are using `id` in your code but it's a built-in function in python so you have to change it in your `urls.py` too:

```
path('teamscores/<int:team_id>', views.teamscores, name="teamscores")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still doesn't work, but if I pass the object's id manually to the function, it works.

Comment: Yes, well, there were no migrations needed as there were no changes to the model.

Comment: Are you hitting the right URL? because you say the function is working fine when you pass the id manually.

Comment: But the problem is I need it to get the id automatically. Typing in the id manually is no good. How can the views function automatically get the id of all/any of my objects?

Comment: `id ` is a built-in function in python so you have to change the name, sorry didn't see that :)